# Replace instead of add a xml node

Tags: c++, pugixml

In this simple code after invoking second(), 1.xml has only one node "1". Why pugi replaces node and what should I do for correct modifying?

```
void first()
{
    pugi::xml_document document;
    pugi::xml_parse_result result = document.load_file("C:\\1.xml", parse_full);
    pugi::xml_node node = document.append_child("0");
    node.append_attribute("message") = "something";
    document.save_file("C:\\1.xml");
}
void second()
{
    pugi::xml_document document;
    pugi::xml_parse_result result = document.load_file("C:\\1.xml", parse_full);
    pugi::xml_node node = document.append_child("1");
    node.append_attribute("message") = "something else";
    document.save_file("C:\\1.xml");
}
void test()
{
    first();
    second();
}
```

Comment: i would check the documentation of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the result of `load_file`.

Here's what's going on here:

1. XML tag names can't start with digits. This is defined by XML standard.
2. pugixml performs this check while loading the document - so `load_file()` fails, producing an empty document
3. pugixml *does not* perform this check while appending nodes or saving document, so it is possible to save an invalid document